# Calling Stitches createStitches for every component in React

Tags: reactjs, stitches

I'm using [Stitches](https://stitches.dev/) to write my CSS in a React application, mainly for the theming and variables. I'm calling `createStitches` in every component file, like so:

**ComponentA.tsx**

```
import { createStitches, styled } from "@stitches/react";

const { createTheme } = createStitches({ theme: {...} });

...

export default ComponentA;
```

**ComponentB.tsx**

```
import { createStitches, styled } from "@stitches/react";

const { createTheme } = createStitches({ theme: {...} });

...

export default ComponentB;
```

And then I'm importing these components and using them in **App.tsx**:

```
import ComponentA from "./components/ComponentA";
import ComponentB from "./components/ComponentB";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know I can just call the `createStitches` in the **App.tsx** file once, but I like keeping my components self-sufficient, as in they should work without any other extra work. Is this a bad approach, or is this something that is fine to do? Does React call the function many times, or just once? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call `createStitches` for every component. This function is to create configuration for your application styling. I don't that you are going to have separate configuration for every component.
This will just cause extra work. Just keep the `createStitches` in a common file and import it from there